# How to cite a film with BibTeX

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

How would I cite a film with BibTeX? My primary problem is getting the directory and producers fields to show up.
I am using the `apacite` for my bibliography package.

I need to get a citation that looks like this:

> Macdonald, A. & Reich, A. (Producers) & Garland, P. (Director). (2015). Ex Machina [Motion picture]. United Kingdom: Universal Studios.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use **biblatex**!.

Here is an example, using biblatex-apa. I had to add lines stating that the director and producer should be used as authors in citations of movies.

```
 \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[american]{babel}
    \usepackage{csquotes}
    \usepackage[style=apa, natbib]{biblatex}
    \DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
    \addbibresource{file.bib}

    \DeclareLabelname[movie]{
      \field{director}
      \field{producer}
    }


    \begin{document}
    I've seen a movie \citep{machida2015}.

    \printbibliography
    \end{document}
```

The **file.bib** file:

```
@movie{machida2015,
  title =   {Ex Machina},
  producer= {Macdonald, A. and Reich, A.}     
  director = {Garland, P.},
  year = {2015},
  publisher = {United Kingdom: Universal Studios.}
}
```

Comment: A tip: for displayed code, select it and click on the `{}` button (or hit Control-K).

Comment: You need a comma after the producer field!

Comment: Where are the modifications you had to make to get this result?

Answer (score 1):

`Biblatex` has `movie` and `video` entry types, but these are unsupported, and they are treated as a `misc` type. You might define custom fields `producer` and `director` and adapt  the macros for another entry type to these types.

Comment: with `@movie{Kurosawa2006SevenSamurai2020v12v02vWedv17h25m40s,` I get "Warning--entry type for "Kurosawa2006SevenSamurai2020v12v02vWedv17h25m40s" isn't style-file defined"