# BibLaTeX: how can an entry type be unsupported?

Tags: biblatex

What follows is not a "how do you do this" question, but a conceptual question about how things work in LaTeX.

If I add a film to a `.bib` database, with the `@movie` type, the bibliography does compile, but there are some error messages that say "no driver type for entry type 'movie'." I see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272404/how-to-cite-a-film-with-bibtex) that the `@movie` entry type is "unsupported." My question is this: what does it mean for an entry type to be unsupported if I can still compile a bibliography with it? And is there a better way to include movies in a bibliography?

Comment: No idea, but I would try with @misc ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because most `biblatex` styles are aimed at the sciences where films are almost never a likely reference type, they don't provide any way to format the `@movie` entry type even though that entry type is a supported entry type at the `.bib` level. This is what it means to say that there is no driver for that entry type.

One style that does support that type is the `mla` style (not surprisingly, since this is a pure humanities style). If you want to add movies to other styles you would need to add the driver code yourself.